# Xcode 6 Beta 4 Broke stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:

Tags: xcode6

Before XC6B4, I could read html from any web site on my local network. Once I updated to XC6B4, all of my local urls stopped working with a very generic error about operation failed. All of my local sites open perfectly in Safari, so I know they're all still valid. If I use any url that's not on my local network, for example http://apple.com or http://espn.go.com, it all works perfectly.

Further, if I launch Xcode 6 Beta 3, then reading html from all of my other local sites works just fine again.

So I opened both XC6B3 and XC6B4 at the same time and opened a playground in each and copied the exact same code into each playground. The code runs perfectly in XC6B3, but that identical code fails in XC6B4.

I'm at a loss as there's no code change that I can make to get around this problem. NSString simply refuses to read from a site on my local network in XC6B4.

Is there some new setting or configuration that I don't know about?

I'd appreciate any help on this matter.

Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved for me by rebooting my iMac. If you're having any weird issues with XC6B4, don't be ashamed to go and and try rebooting. Odd, I know, but it worked.